# WELD-001408: trying @Inject EJB from JAR to WAR

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb, cdi, inject

I've JAR with EJB 3.1 that I need to use in WAR. Both JAR and WAR are deployed separately on same JBoss (AS 7.1). When I inject EJB in one of the CDI beans in WAR I got this error:

```
16:45:19,003 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-1) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."TEST_WEB.war".WeldService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."TEST_WEB.war".WeldService: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type [TestSessionEJBLocal] with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point [[field] @Inject cz.pfreiberg.test.view.portlet.ViewPortlet.testBean]
    at org.jboss.as.weld.services.WeldService.start(WeldService.java:83)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type [TestSessionEJBLocal] with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point [[field] @Inject cz.pfreiberg.test.view.portlet.ViewPortlet.testBean]
        at     org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:275)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:244)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBean(Validator.java:107)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateRIBean(Validator.java:127)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBeans(Validator.java:346)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateDeployment(Validator.java:331)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.validateBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:366)
        at org.jboss.as.weld.WeldContainer.start(WeldContainer.java:83)
        at org.jboss.as.weld.services.WeldService.start(WeldService.java:76)
```

From my current point of view the @Inject doesn’t see the EJB, but if I use manual JNDI lookup (from WAR) is possible for me to get instance of this bean. Is possible to inject EJB from another JAR with @Inject annotation?

Class in WAR (CDI Bean) which @Inject EJB from JAR:

```
@Model
public class ViewPortlet implements Serializable {
     @Inject
     TestSessionEJBLocal testBean;
}
```

EJB class in JAR which I'm trying to @Inject with local and remote interface:

```
@Stateless
public class TestSessionEJBBean implements TestSessionEJB, TestSessionEJBLocal
```

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: Do you have a beans.xml in both your JAR and WAR?

Comment: Yes, I have (one at META-INF for JAR, one at WEB-INF for WAR). According to the specification it is even optional.

Comment: @PetrFreiberg Does it also work with `@EJB` annotations or just for CDI with `@Inject`?

Comment: You can map EJB from another project if you declare full JNDI path in this annotation. Example:
@EJB(mappedName = *full JNDI path to external EJB*)
ExternalSessionEJBLocal bean;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a lot of research probably the only viable solution is to use separate class (EJBProducer) which use CDI @Produces annotation and hides JNDI lookup. Then you can use @Inject inside your application. The only problem is that you've to write JNDI for each bean separately. Here is example:
http://pastebin.com/3V3kKgD9

I must thank Martin Polák for this solution.

Comment: Hi I am wondering if this is still the only viable option. I have a JAR inside of an EAR and would like to do a direct injection from JAR to a separate WAR and I am running into the same error.

Comment: I haven't come up with another solution since.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: *no*

JNDI lookup is the go-to && correct way here.

Your WAR cannot see anything from the JAR file since it does not depend on it. It will most likely be loaded with another class loader as well. If you added the JAR as a dependency, it might work. However, I suppose you do not want to go that way as you have other deployment(s) depending on that JAR.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've dependency to JAR in "jboss-deployment-structure.xml" which lays in WEB-INF of my WAR. Is this not enough? Or there is another type of dependency, that I can set?

Comment: I meant simply adding a Maven `<dependency>` (assuming that is what you use) to your WAR. Plus both archives should have `beans.xml` - theoretically, you don't need it, but it's the easiest way to make sure your classes are picked up as beans. As for `jboss-deployment-structure`, I am not sure it can help here but then again, I barely ever used this feature.